# Hibernate Form Validation Display Error

Tags: spring-mvc, hibernate-validator

I have prepared a sample spring mvc application to understand Hibernate Validator

API.

The view is not getting displayed, when I run it, even though I have all the

required files ready.

The following are my files :

- List item

_

```
@EnableWebMvc 


@Configuration


@ComponentScan({"com.*"})


public class SpringConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {



    public void addHandler(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry)


    {

        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**/").addResourceLocations("/resources/"

);


    }


@Bean


public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver()


{


 InternalResourceViewResolver vr = new InternalResourceViewResolver();


 vr.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");


 vr.setSuffix(".jsp");


 return vr;


}


}
```

- Controller

  @RequestMapping("/form")
  public class FormController {
  @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)

  ```
      public String initForm(Model model) {


          Form form = new Form();


          model.addAttribute("form", form);


          return "form";


      }

      @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)


      public String submitForm(@Valid Form form, BindingResult result) {


          String returnVal = "successForm";


          if(result.hasErrors()) {


              returnVal = "form";


          }


          return returnVal;


      }


  }


                       Model
  ```

  public class Form {

  ```
  @Size(min=5, max=10, message="Should be of 5-10 characters")


  private String name;



  @Min(value = 5, message="Should be atleast of 5 characters")


  private String lastname;


  @NotNull(message="Cannot be empty")


  @Size(min=5, max=10, message="Should be of 5-10 characters")


  private String password;


  @Pattern(regexp="[0-9]+",message="Wrong Zip")


  private String zip;

  @Min(value=18,message="Should not be below 18")


  private String age;


  public String getName() {


      return name;


  }

  public void setName(String name) {


      this.name = name;


  }

  public String getLastname() {


      return lastname;


  }

  public void setLastname(String lastname) {


      this.lastname = lastname;


  }

  public String getPassword() {


      return password;


  }

  public void setPassword(String password) {


      this.password = password;


  }

  public String getZip() {


      return zip;


  }

  public void setZip(String zip) {


      this.zip = zip;


  }


  public String getAge() {


      return age;


  }


  public void setAge(String age) {


      this.age = age;

  }
  ```

  }

  ```
                         JSP
  ```

"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

Insert title here

### Fill your form!

```
<form:form method="POST" commandName="form">


    <table>


        <tr>


            <td>Enter your name:</td>


            <td><form:input path="name" /></td>


            <td><form:errors path="name" cssStyle="color: #ff0000;"/></td>


        </tr>


        <tr>


            <td>Enter your lastname:</td>


            <td><form:input path="lastname" /></td>


            <td><form:errors path="lastname" cssStyle="color: #ff0000;" />
```

```
        </tr>


        <tr>


            <td>Enter your password:</td>


            <td><form:input path="password" /></td>


            <td><form:errors path="password" cssStyle="color: #ff0000;" />
```

```
        </tr>


        <tr>


            <td>Enter your zip:</td>


            <td><form:input path="zip" /></td>


            <td><form:errors path="zip" cssStyle="color: #ff0000;" /></td>


        </tr>


        <tr>


            <td>Enter your email:</td>


            <td><form:input path="email" /></td>


            <td><form:errors path="email" cssStyle="color: #ff0000;" /></td>


        </tr>


        <tr>


            <td>Enter your age:</td>


            <td><form:input path="age" /></td>


            <td><form:errors path="age" cssStyle="color: #ff0000;" /></td>


        </tr>


        <tr>


            <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></td>


        </tr>


        <tr>


    </table>


</form:form>
```

```
                                       pom.xml
```

xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

4.0.0

org.springframework.samples.service.service

HibernateValidation

0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

war

```
<properties>


    <!-- Generic properties -->


    <java.version>1.6</java.version>


    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>


    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-
```

8

```
    <!-- Web -->


    <jsp.version>2.2</jsp.version>


    <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>


    <servlet.version>2.5</servlet.version>


    <!-- Spring -->


    <spring-framework.version>3.2.3.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>



    <!-- Hibernate / JPA -->


    <hibernate.version>4.2.1.Final</hibernate.version>



    <!-- Logging -->


    <logback.version>1.0.13</logback.version>


    <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>



    <!-- Test -->

    <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>

</properties>


<dependencies>


<dependency>
```

javax.el

javax.el-api

2.2.4

```
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>


        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>


        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>


    </dependency>
```

org.glassfish.web

javax.el

2.2.4

```
<dependency>


<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>


<artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>


<version>4.3.10.Final</version>
```

```
<dependency>


<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>


<artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>


<version>3.5.6-Final</version>
```

```
<dependency>


<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>


<artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>


<version>3.3.0.ga</version>
```

```
<groupId>cglib</groupId>


<artifactId>cglib</artifactId>


<version>2.2.2</version>
```

```
<groupId>asm</groupId>


<artifactId>asm-util</artifactId>


<version>3.3.1</version>
```

```
<groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>


<artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>


<version>1.0</version>
```

```
<groupId>mysql</groupId>


<artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>


<version>6.0.3</version>
```

```
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>


<artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>


<version>5.2.4.Final</version>
```

```
<groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>


<artifactId>jta</artifactId>


<version>1.1</version>
```

```
<groupId>javax.validation</groupId>


<artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>


<version>1.1.0.Final</version>
```

```
    <!-- Spring MVC -->


    <dependency>


        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>


        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>


        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>


    </dependency>


    <!-- Other Web dependencies -->


    <dependency>


<groupId>antlr</groupId>


<artifactId>antlr</artifactId>


<version>2.7.7</version>
```

```
    <dependency>


<groupId>dom4j</groupId>


<artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>


<version>1.6.1</version>
```

```
    <dependency>


        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>


        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>


        <version>${jstl.version}</version>


    </dependency>


    <dependency>


        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>


        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>


        <version>${servlet.version}</version>


        <scope>provided</scope>


    </dependency>


    <dependency>


        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>


        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>


        <version>${jsp.version}</version>


        <scope>provided</scope>


    </dependency>



    <!-- Spring and Transactions -->


    <dependency>


        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>


        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>


        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>


    </dependency>


    <dependency>


<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>


<artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>


<version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
```

```
    <!-- Logging with SLF4J & LogBack -->


    <dependency>


        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>


        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>


        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>


        <scope>compile</scope>


    </dependency>


    <dependency>


        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>


        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>


        <version>${logback.version}</version>


        <scope>runtime</scope>


    </dependency>


    <!-- Hibernate -->


    <dependency>


<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>


<artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>


<version>5.2.4.Final</version>
```

```
    <dependency>


        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>


        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>


        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>


    </dependency>


    <!-- Test Artifacts -->


    <dependency>


        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>


        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>


        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>


        <scope>test</scope>


    </dependency>


    <dependency>


        <groupId>junit</groupId>


        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>


        <version>${junit.version}</version>


        <scope>test</scope>


    </dependency>


</dependencies>
```

Comment: I also got a warning : WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:HibernateValidation' did not find a matching property.

Comment: What error you are getting? Does your result.hasErrors() returning true? See what you are missing, try checking my repo here : https://github.com/ankidaemon/sh